# Text overlay on fullscreen video Roku

Tags: video, roku, brightscript

I'm starting developing brightscript with simpleVideoPlayer for Roku, how can I add a text overlay or an image canvas when the video is on fullscreen?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you use roVideoPlayer (instead of roVideoScreen), you can layer an roImageCanvas on top:

http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roVideoPlayer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's too late to answer, but I've dealt with this before.

When using a roVideoPlayer and a roImageCanvas together, the roVideoPlayer is rendered below the image canvas (below layer 0). So if your image canvas has some transparent layers, the roVideoPlayer should show through.

Hope this helps if I'm not too late.